# Apply css styling only if child exists

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```html
<span id="precio">
  <p class="price">
    <del>
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">S/.
        </span>
        120
      </span>
    </del>
    <ins>
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">S/.</span>
        110
      </span>
    </ins>
    <span class="citygo">➤ Incluye el envío</span>
  </p>
</span>
```

what I need is that the css has to be applied only if `.citygo` exist

```css
div#boton_info #precio {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And if it does not exist, apply this

```css
div#boton_info #precio {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

note: The css is more complex, this is just an example, so I simplified it.

There are examples of how to do it when the div that disappears is on top but this time it is on the bottom

Comment: what do you mean with divsbranch? You mean markup? I see no div inside your code. CSS has no if/else-statement with slight exception of media queries. So you need a scripting language to run an if/else-statement.

Comment: hello tacoshy, I understand that it can be done by jQuery but I want to do it only by css I know there is a way.

Been reading about the :has() method but it's not implemented yet.
There must be another method I think?

Comment: correct `:has()` Pseudo-selector is only supported by safari. Not even supported by FF. Like I said you need a scripting language to run an if/else statement. there is no CSS-Hack to it.

Comment: Please edit your title. Currently it makes no sense in English. Do you mean "Apply CSS to child if parent div exists"? Also, you mention `span.citype`, yet it is not in either of your example selectors. There's also no `div#boton_info` in your HTML. Knowing the structure of the HTML is vital to constructing CSS.

Comment: There is a way with CSS, but `.citygo` needs to be an `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, or `<a>`. This is assuming that `#precio` is just the selector since it's parent isn't in the HTML.

Comment: @hereticmonkey span.citygo or .citygo is the same since it is closed by a span
How would the title be to edit it? I don't speak much English

Comment: @zer00ne can i change it to "a" , ".citygo"

Comment: @Club sure you can. Do you want an answer or just a quick comment?

Comment: @zer00ne answer please if you were so kind it is appreciated

Comment: @Club one thing is that it'll only work if the focus is on `<a>` . You still need JavaScript if it just needs to be there without user interaction are you still interested?

Comment: Dear @zer00ne I know how to do it with javascript, my attempt is to do it cleanly only with CSS.
I appreciate the help anyway.